# appearance API availability iOS 7, iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on app that supports both iOS 6 and iOS 7 and I'm using the appearance API to customise the background colour of UINavigationBar and UIToolbar, here's my code

```
if (IS_BELOW_iOS7){
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor A2A_NAVBAR_G1]];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor A2A_NAVBAR_G1]];
}
else{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor A2A_NAVBAR_G1]];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor A2A_NAVBAR_G1]];
}
```

Now the thing is this works perfectly when I run on simulator or build the app for archive but when I try to debug directly to an iPhone running iOS 7 I get the below compilation errors for the 2 lines of code inside the **else** block.

```
No known instance method for selector '`setBarTintColor:`'

No known instance method for selector '`setBarTintColor:`'
```

How can I fix this?

**------EDIT------**

The code above works perfectly on iOS 7 simulator and it also works when I archive the app and install it on iOS 7 device. It only shows the errors when I try to run directly from Xcode to an iOS 7 device.

Comment: When you run the code, is there an existing Navbar and Toolbar already?  your code seems to be right in fact the line the Navbar appearance command is coded exactly as is in the official Apple reference materials.   It maybe trying to look for something to set and if there is no existing navbar or toolbar it fails in the actual device?

Comment: Actually this code is in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the AppDelegate.